# Not good view of menu in Firefox Mozilla?

Tags: css, wordpress, firefox, menu, styles

in my website when I use FireFox I have problem with content of menu.
[wrong menu view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1MBVe.png)

It problem just in firefox.

Comment: Website is - http://chernykh.com.ua

Comment: It would be nice if you could describe the problem in more detail and show us the code you used to implement the menu. Otherwise it will be difficult to find a solution for your problem.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/demo doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Comment: @Paulie_D while I totally agree with you and can understand how it calls for downvoting the question. I don't see why it was necessary to downvote the answers, which are correct. Some people here made a real effort and use their precious time to help another user. Not upvoting them is fine, but downvoting?

Comment: @Paulie_D Yes you are right, it was necessary to insert the code, it's just a little hard to believe that someone is able to visually see the problem through the code, when I can not see the problem, I feel stupid ...

Comment: @Mr.Flowers Despite all that is said above, there are 2 correct & valid answers to your question below, by users who indeed made a bigger effort to understand the question & help you. It would be nice if you pick one of them as the correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at [your website](http://chernykh.com.ua/),

[image]

your [CSS](http://chernykh.com.ua/wp-content/themes/unicase/style.css) shows:

```
.navbar .navbar-nav li .dropdown-menu .menu-item-has-children > a::after,
.widget_unicase_nav_menu .navbar-nav li .dropdown-menu .menu-item-has-children > a::after{
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  content: '\f105';
  float: right; }
```

While it should be:

```
.navbar .navbar-nav li .dropdown-menu .menu-item-has-children > a::before,
.widget_unicase_nav_menu .navbar-nav li .dropdown-menu .menu-item-has-children > a::before {
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  content: '\f105';
  float: right; }
```

Change the two `after` to `before`.
This will align the menu arrows correctly in all browsers.

Alternatively, add `position:absolute; right:5px;` to your code.

Comment: Big thanx for you - @CM-웃  - But you can explane for me, why this problem was just in Firefox?  And on the mobile phone are very sensitive buttons of menu and sometimes instead of opening the subsection of the menu - opens the section, I thought it connected with tag-position, but not. What could be the problem?

Comment: @Mr.Flowers Firefox engine has its own quirks. If you have additional questions, I suggest you post new questions, but this time, please make sure you ask them correctly: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, otherwise - your account may get blocked for further posts on SO due to asking low quality questions repeatedly.

Comment: @AnnieTrubak OK :)

Answer (score 0):

I have checked your Firefox related designing issue so please
use below css code in your style.css

> Note: It will be done for Firefox issue.

```
.navbar .navbar-nav li .dropdown-menu .menu-item-has-children > a::after, .widget_unicase_nav_menu .navbar-nav li .dropdown-menu .menu-item-has-children > a::after {
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    content: '\f105';
    float: right;
    top: 0;
    position: absolute;
    right: 5px;
}
```